# draw2d imports not resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I am doing an eclipse plugin using gef. When I restart eclipse after a plugin installation I got a lot of errors regarding draw2d imports. For example in one of my classes I had:

```
import org.eclipse.draw2d.ImageFigure;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.Label;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.MouseMotionListener;
```

the 3 last imports were fine but the first one "import org.eclipse.draw2d.ImageFigure"
could not anymore be resolved.

I can not figure out what is going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: The errors came up when I installed the google CodePro AnalytiX plugin and gone away when unistalled them. Can understand how this plugin is affecting draw2d imports....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the solution. The plugin was using its own version of draw2d.jar file. I manually replace that file with the draw2d.jar from the eclipse GEF plugin and everything was working fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have org.eclipse.draw2d in Required Plug-ins(plugin.xml -> Dependencies)? If no - add and try to rebuild plugin, if yes - ... remove and add once again?

Comment: yes i have that. My project works fine. The problems only shows when I install the google CodePro AnalytiX plugin. If I remove that plugin imports are again fine. Do not know how this plugin is affecting the draw2d imports

Comment: Maybe this plugin comes with other version of draw2d than 'your' eclipse use by default and in this version ImageFigure object doesn't exist or is somewhere else(in different package) - try to check which version of draw2d is loaded when CodePro is not installed, set this version as required version in plugin.xml->Dependencies->draw2d->properties, install CodePro and run your plugin.